# my eval operator not working on pandas Series object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, eval

I have a dataframe with a column that has the final score of the superbowl from 1967-2021. It is a string in the format of

> winners score - losers score

ie.

> 24-10

[image]

now the score is only useful if I can get the difference between the winning and losing points.

I decided to create a pandas series with just the score column so i can iterate over each row and apply the **eval()** function and append the result to an empty list

```
scores = game_data['Score']
score_list = []
for x in scores:
   score_list.append(eval(x))
```

however i get this error:

[image]

is there any other way I can take the string values of the column and perform the minus operator?

edit:

some people said that the minus sign in the values may not be a minus sign at all but then would it still be of type string? since i printed out the type of each value in the column and it came out as a string.

Comment: Is that dash really a minus sign? It looks longer.

Comment: im pretty sure it is a minus sign. what else can it be? but i did assign an index element  from the series to a variable and i get the same issue

Comment: @GirthyLampost the various other dash-like unicode glyphs that exist, of course, that *would* throw a syntax error. That being said, **you must provide a [mcve]**. Do **not** post images of code or error messages. Indeed, if you had posted text, this could probably be answered easily. Otherwise, we are just going to sit around guessing

Comment: In any case, you probably shouldn't be using `eval` at all. And note, `eval` is not an operator, it is a function

Comment: At the *very* least, you should provide the output of `print(repr(a))`

Comment: okay i will rewrite my question with the proper details

Comment: i think i posted all the necessary info for my question

Comment: There are many kinds of dashes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Unicode

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of some code that you could use. Rather than using the eval() function, I would recommend using the string split method on the score column, and then converting the two scores into integers so that you can do the subtraction.

```
# I created a sample dataframe to tinker with
df_scores = pd.DataFrame({'Final_Scores':['22-10','35-14'], 'Winners':['Falcons', 'Chargers'], 'Losers':['Eagles', 'Texans']})

# This is the key: splitting the string so that you can operate with the two scores
df_split_scores = df_scores['Final_Scores'].str.split(pat='-', expand=True)

# I renamed the columns of the split scores, joined them to the original datafram, and then converted them to integers
df_split_scores.rename(columns={0: "Winner_Score", 1: "Loser_Score"}, inplace=True)
df_scores = df_scores.join(df_split_scores)
df_scores['Winner_Score'] = df_scores['Winner_Score'].astype(int)
df_scores['Loser_Score'] = df_scores['Loser_Score'].astype(int)

# Then, I found the difference between the winner's score and the loser's score.
df_scores['Spread'] = df_scores['Winner_Score'] - df_scores['Loser_Score']
```